# How to replace Excel save button with my own Save As code?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code I have made that works perfectly to rename my =JE Template file to a new name pulled from the worksheet. However, I want to put this into the BeforeSave Sub so it runs this code anytime the Save button is clicked so my =JE Template file won't get saved over and to avoid confusion. However, at this point with the code as it is, it goes into an infinite loop because it obviously keeps going back to the BeforeSave event every time the macro runs to save the file. My question is, how do I make it stop so it won't go into an endless loop?

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim File_Name
Dim Old_File As String
Dim New_File As String
Dim Answer_Yes As String
Dim Answer_No As String

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

File_Name = Range("File_Name")
Old_File = ActiveWorkbook.FullName

Application.EnableEvents = False

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & File_Name & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

New_File = ActiveWorkbook.FullName

If InStr(Old_File, "=JE Template") = 0 = True Then
If InStr(Old_File, New_File) = 0 = True Then
Answer_Yes = MsgBox("Delete old file?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "User Response")
If Answer_Yes = vbYes Then
Kill Old_File
End If
End If
End If

ErrorHandler:
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

I have the below code elsewhere but they are in their on Modules and don't have any Save code in them so I wouldn't think they would affect anything.

```
Public Function LastRow() As Long

Application.Volatile
Worksheets("JE Cover").AutoFilterMode = False
LastRow = Worksheets("JE Cover").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

End Function

Sub Add_Row()

Range("A1").Select
Cells.Find(What:="*Last Row*", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=-1, columnOffset:=0).Activate
Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Worksheets("Entry Detail").Activate
Range("B9").Formula2R1C1 = "=IFERROR(lastrow(),"""")"
Worksheets("JE Cover").Activate
Range("A1").Select

End Sub


Function GetFirstLetters(rng As Range) As String

Dim arr
Dim I As Long
arr = VBA.Split(rng, " ")
If IsArray(arr) Then
    For I = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        GetFirstLetters = GetFirstLetters & Left(arr(I), 1)
    Next I
Else
    GetFirstLetters = Left(arr, 1)
End If

End Function
```

Comment: Turn off the events before saving then turn it back on before leaving the sub: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.enableevents

Comment: So I would just need to put Application.EnableEvents = False right before the ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs line and the put Application.EnableEvents = True right before End Sub?

Comment: Make sure you put the `Application.EnableEvents = True` also in you error handling right before `Exit Sub` just in case an error happens when trying to save.  We need to make sure the events are turned back on or they will stay off.

Comment: So I changed the code and it is still going into a loop and crashing on me, can you please see above updated code and advise? Am I not putting them in the correct place. I initially thought the Application.EnableEvents was the answer but just wasn't sure how to properly utilize them.

Comment: I tested your code, works as a charm, no looping going on. Do you have other events what cause the looping?

Comment: I tried it again just to confirm and it does save it but then just spins and eventually crashes. I added any other code I have to my question but as I noted any other code is in its own module and doesn't have anything to do with saving the file so don't think it would affect it

Comment: @JamieWalker Your save function looks like it's called by a button or something and not in the event code `OnBeforeSave` - how are you calling it? Code you posted looks okay, but I would be interested in whether or not you have any other events firing during the save process. How is your function called?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I was calling it with a button but realized quickly that people will out of habit click the Excel Save button and save over my template so I am trying to move it to the BeforeSave to try to avoid that. I have updated my question to reflect this